# Lost my default weapons in Garry's Mod

Tags: garrys-mod

I went onto some random server and I didn't spawn with my default weapons. All I had was a physics gun. Which was what I was spawned with when I started a singleplayer game after this. I had nothing else. How can I get the other guns back?

Comment: have you tried going to the game menu (press "q") > admin > enable weapons?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't work. Does nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the console (Press "~") and enter `sbox_weapons 1`. Respawn and the weapons will be restored

Answer (score 0):

Hold <kbd>Q</kbd> to open the Spawn Menu. There is a "Weapons" tab at the top. Click on the weapons you want to spawn.

Answer (score 0):

Start a game, hold down <kbd>Q</kbd>, and click the tab that says "Utilities", A.K.A the tab to the right of the tab that says "Tools". Then click the thing under "ADMIN" that says "Settings". When you click on it, there will be some boxes with checkmarkss in a couple of the boxes. Look for the box that says "Enable weapons". Click on it, and when you're done, your guns still won't be there. So exit the game and return to it again. Your guns should be back. If it happens on another server, just repeat.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to console (whatever its set to; 'U' usually, but if not set go to options, console on and set a key)
2. type this: sbox_weapons 1:enter exit
3. Go back to console and type:kill
4. Your weapons should now be back

Answer (score -2):

My pc is really laggy so the utilities tab didn't download right. The answer is to just go to admin and check off 'enable weapons' and die, then you get back your weapons.

Answer (score -2):

uninstall and reinstall garrys mod that works for me.